# How to connect socket.io with a Heroku-deployed React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-native, socket.io

I have almost googled my fingers off trying to figure this out. It seems a lot of the existing info on connecting socket.io with React Native is outdated, or maybe I'm just interpreting things wrong?

I've managed to get the client-side connected (I'm getting the client console logs when I connect to my app). It seems to be the server-side that's giving me issues. Why is the data being emitted from the client not showing up as a log in my terminal? None of the related console.logs in my server.js are logging but the App.js console.logs are registering.

Edit: **Here is my full App.js file:**

```
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import store from './src/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


// window.navigator.useragent = 'react-native'; -> not necessary anymore?



const ROOT_URL = 'https://myherokudomain.herokuapp.com';

const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');
const socket = io.connect(ROOT_URL);


socket.on('connect', () => {
     console.log('Connected to server');
});


socket.on('example', (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});


socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected from server');
});

export default class App extends React.Component {


render() {

// const MainNavigator = my react-navigation system

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MainNavigator />
    </View>
  </Provider>
  );
 }
}
```

Edit: **Here is my full server.js file:**

```
const config = require('./config/config');
const { mongoose } = require('./db/mongoose');
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

// ************ Include and use separate routes file
app.use(require('./routes/routes'));
// ************


//Cross-Origin resource sharing. cors library solves CORS problems.
app.use(cors());


//***********
/* Chat server code*/


// enabled heroku session affinity: 
// see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity
// to enable:   heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
// to diable:   heroku features:disable http-session-affinity

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');


const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIO(server, { origin: "*:*" });
//********** */


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A client just joined', socket.id);

    socket.emit('example', { hello: 'world' });

    socket.on('my other event', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User was disconnected');
    });
});


server.listen(port, (err) => {
    console.log(`started on port ${port}`);
});



module.exports = { app };
```

I am getting the console logs on the client side just fine (for instance, the "connected to server" and "hello: world" stuff is showing up when I open my app on expo. But I am not getting the server-side console logs.

What am I doing wrong - how do I get socket.io fully working with a deployed React-Native app?

I would really appreciate any help at all! I've been stuck on this forever.

Comment: Please post your `App.js` file.

Comment: Hi Colin, I just posted everything in my App.js (except I removed the react-navigation stuff to shorten it up since it's irrelevant)

Comment: Are you sure `const socket = io.connect(ROOT_URL);` is correct?

Comment: I believe it is correct since ROOT_URL is my heroku domain, and when I open my app on my phone I get the client-side "Connected to server" log.

Comment: Honestly, I think that your naming of `socket` and `io` are getting confused somewhere. I'd go through the tutorial again and just make sure the names are right.

Comment: I've spent crazy hours on this. Pretty sure something simple like my variable names isn't the issue haha. But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: If you make a CodeSandbox I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I would seriously love you forever if you fixed it and probably be willing to pay you too lol. This one stupid thing has held up my app development for days now. I'm going to the gym but I will see about making a sandbox when I get back

Comment: No worries, I'll look at it whenever you post.

Comment: Thank you so much Colin. Not necessary now, I'm an idiot and my code was working properly, I just wasn't checking for the logs in the right place and made some bad assumptions. I really appreciate you, thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming all the code works, just not the logging since that's all you're asking about. The problem is Node doesn't output to your browser's console.

If it's deployed on heroku then you should see everything being logged there, otherwise you can use libraries like https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector to output to your browser.

Comment: Matt you are a life saver!! I had it solid in my head that the socket-related logs should be showing up in my mac terminal so I assumed my implementation was wrong and kept focusing on changing code on the server and client... and I completely neglected to check the heroku logs. OMG! When I checked heroku logs everything was there as you said. My data is being emitted and logged there. I am obviously such a noob at some things still. Thank you!! <3

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the server-side console logs because 1.) They're only logging on the server, and 2.) You're not emitting them, if you do actually want to send the data back.

Comment: In App.js I am emitting -> 

socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });

as a test and that doesn't show up in the terminal.

Comment: Also, the server isn't showing me a log when I connect or disconnect from my app (but I get the client-related logs). In theory I should at least be getting the "A client just joined" log as seen in server.js but that's not happening